# Foreign Key in Laravel 5.1 - NO Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

Need Help guys!  Whats wrong with my migrations, It's not creating a relationship between `users` table and `posts` table. Here's what I did:

1. migrate users table
2. create posts table
3. migrate posts table with foreign key

**Users Migration**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**Posts Migration**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->text('content');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```

Nothing Happen with my database. Take a look at my database:
[image]

**Compared** with this:
[image]

.. I'm using **Laravel 5.1**

Comment: Any error? Post that to?

Comment: Check if their column definitions (types, sizes) are equal on the db.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz No error showing.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes, they are the same.

Comment: In what order are the post and user migrations in your migration folder?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan What do you mean "In what order"?  their place in `migration folder` ?  `users` migration is the first and the `posts` migration is the next one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it in two step. `Schema::create()` is only used to create table.

To add relation you need to write it within `Schema::table()`.

Try following :

**In `CreatePostsTable` :**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: @LaravelMan if table is already created you need to add  new migration file and assign foreign key code in that file, and run migration.

Comment: @MeeraTank I have also tried it, but still not working

Comment: If you don't have any data. Rollback the migration and run it again.

Comment: @PankitGami I dont have any data, hmm I tried your answer but still not working.